# What is the replacement for the gwt-google-apis?

Tags: google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3, google-api

Currently have some code using this:
https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/

Since it hasn't been updated in years, and google code is going away...
I was wondering what the current approach/libraries are for accessing google apis from within GWT.

Comment: For maps there's https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api

Comment: I had come across that, but it hasn't been updated in a year by the looks of it :S

Comment: If that is the "standard", I guess we can fork it and start maintaining / contributing, but had hoped for a slightly more official/active library.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good alternative would be to use the [google map web component](http://googlewebcomponents.github.io/google-map/components/google-map/) with JSInterop.